# WinJS programmatically take screenshot of app

Tags: cordova, windows-8.1, winjs

I'm working on a Cordova application for Windows 8.1 and I'm trying to build a plugin that can take a screenshot of the app.  I've looked around MSDN, but haven't found anything that can do that.  This kind of plugin exists for iOS and Android ( https://github.com/gitawego/cordova-screenshot ), but I haven't been able to find a Windows equivalent for this yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a good way to do this.

Windows Store apps don't have any explicit screenshot API (Windows Phone Store apps do have a phone-only [ScreenCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.screencapture.aspx) API) and HTML and JavaScript don't provide a way to render arbitrary HTML to a bitmap (such as Xaml's [RenderTargetBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx)). You render the contents of a Canvas or a WebView, but not the page itself.

Depending on what you have in your HTML you may be able to use a library such as http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ to traverse the DOM and render it into a Canvas which you can convert to a bitmap with [toDataUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975241%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Any idea if this kind of API is on the feature roadmap at all?